# como puedo evitar el siguiente error en Left_join de dplyr

Tags: r, rstudio, join, r-dplyr

tengo las siguientes bases de datos y al tratar de hacer un left_join, me arroja el siguiente error después de compilar el siguiente código:

```
BASE2=NULL
BASE2$ID1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
BASE2$NAME=c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G")
BASE2=as.data.frame(BASE2)

BASE3=NULL
BASE3$ID2=c(1,2,4,7,8,9,10)
BASE3$NAME=c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G")
BASE3=as.data.frame(BASE3)


BASE1=dplyr::left_join(BASE2,BASE3,c("ID1","ID2"))
```

```
Error in `dplyr::left_join()`:
! Join columns in `x` must be present in the data.
✖ Problem with `ID2`.
```

Answer (score 2):

Ya encontre el error

```
BASE2=NULL
BASE2$ID1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
BASE2$NAME=c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G")
BASE2=as.data.frame(BASE2)

BASE3=NULL
BASE3$ID2=c(1,2,4,7,8,9,10)
BASE3$NAME=c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G")
BASE3=as.data.frame(BASE3)


BASE1=dplyr::left_join(BASE2,BASE3,by=c("ID1" = "ID2"))
```

Se debe colocar un signo igual (=) y un by.